# Maiuscola per gli aggettivi con riferimento ad una regione (pianura lombarda, autostrada veneta, Alto Milanese)

Tags: adjectives, capitalization, orthography

Volevo capire l'utilizzo della maiuscola sugli aggettivi che fanno riferimento ad un nome di un luogo, nella fattispecie: una regione.

Per esempio io scriverei "autostrada veneta" e non "autostrada Veneta", oppure "pianura lombarda" e non "pianura Lombarda". Volevo sapere qual'è la forma corretta, e se per caso valesse anche in questo caso la regola che "Lombardo o Veneti" indica il riferimento ad un abitante o agli abitanti della regione.

Inoltre anche gli aggettivi riferiti a parti di regione sono abbastanza controversi per esempio vedo scritto  con la lettera maiuscola non solo "Alto Adige" ma anche "Alto Vicentino", "Bassa Padovana", "Alto Milanese" o addirittura "Basso Veneto". Qual è quindi la regola generale?

Comment: Minuscola, senza alcun dubbio, come aggettivo. E anche come sostantivo: *I veneti abitano in Veneto*. Qualcuno usa la maiuscola per riferirsi a popolazioni antiche: *I Veneti erano una popolazione di origine indoeuropea*.

Comment: @egreg grazie per l'aiuto! Ho provato ad integrare la domanda...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

il nome di un toponimo è in maiuscolo mentre l'aggettivo (o il nome degli abitanti) è in minuscolo, e fin qua direi che si è tutti d'accordo. 
In denominazioni come Alto Milanese chi usa il maiuscolo intende (implicitamente) che almeno per lui il territorio indicato è molto specifico. In effetti se si parla di "milanese" inteso come territorio che gravita su Milano la maiuscola non la si usa mai. Diciamo che se uno scrive "alto milanese" nessuno alza un sopracciglio.

Comment: Quindi fa lo stesso per "la Bassa Padana", dove "Padana" è probabilmente la sostantivizzazione dell'aggettivo che sottintende la parola "pianura"?

Comment: ecco, se mai fossi costretto a usare quel termine probabilmente parlerei di Bassa Padania :-) (proprio perché padana si riferisce a pianura)

Comment: "Padania" è un sostantivo sul cui uso c'è disaccordo. "Bassa Padana" esiste invece e si sente (http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bassa_padana), e tra l'altro è presente anche in una canzone di Battiato ("voglio vederti danzare").

Comment: mmm non mi è ancora chiaro ma comunque a questo punto penso che sia una convenzione, quindi dire "alto vicentino" o "Alto Vicentino" è comunque giusto?

Comment: Il riferimento a *alto vicentino* potrebbe essere ambiguo: si parla di Schio o di un giocatore di basket della città di Palladio? Un po' tirata per i capelli, direi.

Comment: @egreg osservazione molto arguta! :-) Opterò per la forma con la maiuscola allora!

Comment: vd anche il punto 7 in  http://lemmiedilemmi.it/post/2628609810/aggettivo-si-concorda-di-regola-con-il e il cap. I punto 194.h della Grammatica del Serianni (citata qui http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2781812 )